# Make ctrl-a work for readonly textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have an issue with my textbox, i want to select everything from a textbox that is readonly. The text that appears in the textbox is a ouput of another function that checks if our databases has no corruptions. The ouput will appear in the textbox.

So what im trying to do is to select everything from a readonly textbox. So we can save to ouput of the database check.

i've tried this so far:

```
private void ContentTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Control works");
    }
}
```

But now i have to make the "a" key work and i have to make the combination select the textbox.text

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A) {
  //Your code here
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `KeyDown()` method to your TextBox, which recognises a user hitting `Ctrl + A` and then selects all of the text, like:

```
private void ContentTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        ContentTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to code the KeyDown method of your textbox. Something like:

```
private void ContentTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + a detected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
{
   textBox.Focus();
   textBox.SelectionStart = 1;  //start
   textBox.SelectionLength = 2;  //length
   textBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```